# How do I initialize a variable in a try-catch?

Tags: c#

I have a variable in a try-catch that isn't initializing.

```
try
{
    var customcontroldata = svc.queryLookupsXml("customcontroldata");
}
catch
{
    Response.Write(@"<script>alert('We laugh at you');window.location.replace('Accounts.aspx');</script>");
    Response.End();
 }
```

I've tried to initialize the variable outside of the try-catch to no completion.  How would i get the customcontroldata variable to initialize in this method which also is used later in my code?

Comment: Initialize it to what?

Comment: @canon then the try/catch would be empty, and thus pointless.

Comment: well when i write it the variable is grayed out.  so its like var (gray)customercontroldata(/gray)  = and the error i get on compile is "the name customecontroldata" does nto exist in the current context.

Comment: Perhaps better insert that code what you tried to do

Comment: check svc.queryLookupsXml and see what it returns.

Comment: what does the method do?....i ask because you are passing the name of the var variable to your method and var cannot be used in the initialization expression.

Comment: svc.queryLookupsXml returns: XmlNode LoanRouterSErvice.queryLookupsXml(string codeName)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You will want to declare the variable outside of your `try` block. You can assign it to null, then after your `catch`, check if it's null before doing anything with it.

In this case you would also want to be specific about the type of object it is, because you won't be able to assign it to the final value you want when it is declared, because that would happen in your `try`.

Answer (score 3):

```
        XmlNode customcontroldata = null;
        try
        {
            customcontroldata = svc.queryLookupsXml("customcontroldata");
        }
        catch
        {
           Response.Write(@"<script>alert('We laugh at you');window.location.replace('Accounts.aspx');</                    script>");
            Response.End();
        }
```

Comment: This won't work because .NET doesn't know what type `null` is when you would compile the program, which it must know for `var` types

Comment: Could just use `object` as a stand-in.

Comment: @canon: It's not necessary to use a stand-in. The OP wrote in a comment that his method returns an `XmlNode`.

Comment: @ProgramFOX my comment was in relation to your use of [`CorrectTypeHere`](http://stackoverflow.com/revisions/19141088/1). At the time the OP hadn't clarified the return type of `svc.queryLookupsXml()`.

Answer (score 1):

In your code, `customcontroldata` is scoped within the try block, and therefore doesn't exist outside that scope.  Try declaring it outside the try as follows...

```
myObjectType customcontroldata; = null4
try
{
    customcontroldata = svc.queryLookupsXml("customcontroldata");
}
catch
{
    Response.Write(@"<script>alert('We laugh at you');window.location.replace('Accounts.aspx');</                    script>");
    Response.End();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You want to declare the variable outside of the Try/Catch block, initialize to a null/empty value.

You can do the assignment inside the block but ALWAYS test if the variable is null/empty if you plan on using it outside of the TryCatch block.